# AWS Quicksight SSO with KeyCloak

Tags: amazon-web-services, single-sign-on, keycloak, amazon-quicksight

I have been trying to setup AWS Quicksight SSO with Keycloak version 10.0.2. I have been following these three blogs and articles

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/external-identity-providers-setting-up-saml.html

https://scandiweb.com/blog/sign-in-to-amazon-aws-using-saml-protocol-and-keycloak-as-identity-provider#:~:text=Amazon%20AWS%20Service%20Provider%20setup&text=2)%20Go%20to%20%E2%80%9CIAM%E2%80%9D,%E2%80%9D%20and%20then%20%E2%80%9CCreate%E2%80%9D.

and this
https://www.wolfe.id.au/2017/11/05/aws-user-federation-with-keycloak/

I am stuck at the step of creating AWS roles and mappers in Keycloak client settings:

```
kcadm.sh create clients/6c684579-51a1-4bdf-a694-d641199874d8/roles -r wolfeidau -s 'name=arn:aws:iam::981394234017:role/wolfeidau-admin,arn:aws:iam::981394234017:saml-provider/docker-keycloak'
```

> `null [Character ':' not allowed.]`

How do I create a way to create AWS roles and mapper in Keycloak Client settings?

Answer (score 1):

Following [this](https://medium.com/@karanbir.tech/aws-connect-saml-based-identity-provider-using-keycloak-9b3e6d0111e6) blog, I've faced same issue.
But I've found another one workaround that looks much better for me.

Solution is to create "Hardcoded attribute" instead of "Role list" param along with a role creation. So, I use below params:

```
Protocol = saml
Name = Session Role
Mapper Type = Hardcoded attribute
Friendly Name = Session Role
SAML Attribute Name = https://aws.amazon.com/SAML/Attributes/Role
SAML Attribute NameFormat = Basic
Attribute value = arn:aws:I am::<aws account number>:role/<role-for-sso>,arn:aws:I am::<aws account number>:saml-provider/<saml-provider-name>
```

Comment: that guy gave solution at the end of the article / blog you shared above.It worked for me flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a recent Keycloak change. I have existing roles with a colon in the name, but the latest version won't let me create a new role with the colon in the name.

Work around I applied:

- Create the role name without a colon. I chose the format aws-accountNumber-RoleName.
- Add a Role Name Mapper in your AWS client. Keycloak will accept a colon in the "New Role Name" field.